# Retriving the MarketCap of a security

Tags: pine-script

I have been unsuccessful on retrieving the market cap of a security. This is what I have tried :

```
AAPL_Market_cap = request.financial("NASDAQ:AAPL", "MKT_CAP", "FQ")

AAPL_Market_cap = request.financial("NASDAQ:AAPL", "MARKET_CAPITALIZATION", "FQ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Market Capitalization is partially based on the stock price, so it cannot be directly requested via `request.financial()`. [You need to request total shares and multiply them by close](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000564727):

```
TSO = request.financial("NASDAQ:AAPL", "TOTAL_SHARES_OUTSTANDING", "FQ")
MarketCap = TSO * close
```

Comment: how does one request it of the currently viewed security?